# Why are `$create*Node` and `$is*Node` functions prefixed with dollar, when they don't seem to be Lexical context dependent?

Tags: lexicaljs

In [Lexical](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/) source code, alongside with every node class, there are also `$create*Node` and `$is*Node` functions being exported - [for example](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/blob/de85505aed5e8ae82bf4746105ba637efdd6c84a/packages/lexical/src/nodes/LexicalTextNode.js#L994):

```js
export function $createTextNode(text?: string = ''): TextNode {
  return new TextNode(text);
}

export function $isTextNode(node: ?LexicalNode): boolean %checks {
  return node instanceof TextNode;
}
```

The same pattern is [explicitely encouraged in documentation](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/).

But why the dollar prefixes? [According to documentation](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/), the prefix denotes functions which "leverage the lexical scope":

> This is when we decided to leverage the "lexical" scope instead to perform EditorState manipulation, and the $ represents just that.

But judging from the implementation, `$create*Node` and `$is*Node` seem to be just regular functions, that can be called from anywhere. So what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of historical reference: https://lexical.dev/docs/faq#why-does-lexical-use-the--prefix-in-the-name-of-many-of-the-functions

**It's an exception.**

The reason behind this exception is that node manipulation should only be done inside closures. When you think about what you can do with nodes, you quickly realize that storing a reference outside is dangerous and can lead to subtle errors.

For example:

```
// DO NOT COPY! THIS IS BAD
let textNode;
editor.update(() => {
  ...
  textNode = $createTextNode();
  paragraph.append(textNode);
});
setTimeout(() => {
  editor.update(() => {
    textNode.setTextContent('foo');
  });
}, 3000);
```

In the example above, I just appended a `textNode` first, later I am changing its text to `foo`.

What's the catch? This will break if `textNode` is not the latest EditorState one. Let's say that between second 0 and 3000 I typed some characters, `textNode` is no longer the latest node (keep in mind that nodes are immutable) so when I'm trying to use `textNode` later I'm modifying the wrong node.

Instead, you want to store key references:

```
let textNodeKey;
editor.update(() => {
  ...
  const textNode = $createTextNode();
  textNodeKey = textNode.getKey();
  paragraph.append(textNode);
});
setTimeout(() => {
  editor.update(() => {
    const node = $getNodeByKey(textNodeKey);
    if (node !== null) {
      $getNodeByKey(textNodeKey).setTextContent('foo');
    }
  });
}, 3000);
```

That said, this rule mostly applies to `$isXNode`, on node creation we often generate a unique node key and mark the node dirty, both of these actions require access to the current or pending EditorState, which you wouldn't have access outside the closures.